# SharePoint Foundation 2010 and BDC with SQL

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint-2010, database-connection, bdc

Everything I've read on setting up External Content Types with BDC seems to use SharePoint 2010, rather than SharePoint Foundation (SPF) 2010 (the free version).  Even though it also includes BDC, it doesn't seem to include support for creating a Secure Store App ID for alternate credentials (like full-blown SP does).  I cannot seem to get an External List to read from a SQL database table because of this.  I'm using a Database that is on the same server as my SPF installation, so it's not doing any remote connections.  Can anyone point me to something helps explain this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Secure Store is for Standard+.

This link might help you on the right path:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3331/sharepoint-2010-foundation-bcs-errors/

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing a bunch of articles, the solution appears to be explained here: http://wyldesharepoint.blogspot.com/2010/06/setting-up-external-content-type-for.html